# Swift and Core Data Performance on an iPad Pro

Tags: swift, core-data

I don't have much experience with Core Data and Swift. Can someone tell me how quickly I could do a fetch from Core Data of 500 records, save the fetch in an array, and add 500 representative UIViews to a view on an iPad Pro? Each record will have very few properties, maybe 4 integers and a string. This is going to be a game that adds buttons to the screen. When each is clicked it would update the corresponding record so next time the view is displayed we see which buttons were previously clicked. The data has to persist between app sessions. Thanks for your input.

Comment: This will be no problem from a CoreData perspective.  But managing 500 UIViews might be (both speed and memory, depending on their complexity).  UITableViews and UICollectionViews both work on the basis of reusable views for that reason.

Comment: The UIViews are just simple buttons, 50px square with selected and unselected states. All the buttons must be on the screen. I can't use a tableview or collection view.